# Cannot comment on closed/on hold questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, closed-questions, ios-app

As the title says, once a question is closed or put in hold, the comment button in iOS app is gone.

Comments for some questions that are closed as duplicate and spam may not be useful, but they become useful on questions marked as off-topic while it is on-topic on another site and questions that is unclear of what the OP is asking.

Can the **comment** button be added back?

Comment: Please start tagging properly with relevant tag for the app, otherwise people will close your questions. You can't rely on others to retag on your behalf.

Comment: @AlE. no. That one you linked to is for android app, since the apps got different teams, each should have its own report. Retagging this as bug for iOS app only, and let's hope it get fixed soon. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, I'll find some time to study the tags.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same team, different people. :)

Comment: @Brian hmm... good to know - but still, better have separate reports/requests right?

Comment: @ShadowWizard definitely

Comment: I just checked the code and you should be able to comment on closed questions.  Our only check is whether or not you're logged in and the question is locked. Can you reference a specific question?

Comment: @BrianNickel I will post a screenshot of a closed question and an on-holded question.

Comment: As you see, your question is marked as not reproduced. You maybe consider adding that screenshot :)